# Windows 10 : Cannot run "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12" Error

Tags: vb.net, windows-10

I am using Windows 10 Home (x64), when I run the application (x86 -> read .xlsx).

The application just show me

> "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"

```
Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + xcFileInfo.ToString + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
   con.Open()
   table = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
   Dim sheetname As String = table.Rows(0)("table_name").ToString
   Dim myDA As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetname + "]", con)
   myDA.Fill(myTable)
End Using
```

Comment: Try change the target CPU to X64 and test agian.